# How do I localize a date field in an SOQL query?

Tags: soql, date, localization

Per the docs on the [FORMAT() function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_format.htm), I can localize numeric, datetime, and currency fields in an SOQL query by wrapping the field name in FORMAT().  This does not work for date fields; I either get an empty result or a JSON parsing error.  Specifically,

```
SELECT Id, Format(CloseDate) FROM Opportunity
```

yields

```
You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String {"totalSize":35,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0064100000ACH41AAH"},"Id":"0064100000ACH41AAH","CloseDate"}]}[{"message":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]: {"totalSize":35,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0064100000ACH41AAH"},"Id":"0064100000ACH41AAH","CloseDate"}]}[{"message":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

I do not run into this with numeric, currency, or datetime fields.  Is this a known issue and is there a good workaround?

Comment: Please add your snippet which you are using for deserializing, you might get better support with that.

Comment: This is in the Developer Console; I'm not doing the deserializing.  When I make the query using the REST query API, I get:

`{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0064100000ACH41AAH"},"Id":"0064100000ACH41AAH","editDate"}]}[{"message":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]`

which is indeed not valid JSON.

Comment: @NealGroothuis I am facing the same issue with the Date field. How did you resolve this? Did you find any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I didn't.  We're localizing it ourselves, which means we don't have the benefit of knowing what SF believes the locale of the user is.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used the Query Editor in the developer console and got that error. However, if you use the Format() in code, I think it would work.

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, format(CloseDate) editDate FROM Opportunity limit 1];
system.debug(opp);
system.debug(opp.get('editDate'));
```

Comment: I did indeed use the Query Editor in the developer console.  However, I get the same error when I submit the query using the REST query API.

Comment: Yes, it is. -.-